# Rails deploy fails, as SSHKit command failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

The latest in rails 6 deployment problems when compiling javascript assets.  The error points to

```
    1: from /Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in 
'rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as deploy@16.17.18.2: rake exit status: 1 
(SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)

[...]

Caused by:
SSHKit::Command::Failed: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: yarn install v1.22.17
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 25.51s.
Compiling...
Compilation failed:
rake stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy@16.17.18.2: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: yarn install v1.22.17
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 25.51s.
Compiling...
Compilation failed:
rake stderr: Nothing written
```

I have no clue what is going on here.  How should this be addressed?

Comment: Looks like your remote deploy process is hiding errors. What happens if you SSH to deploy@... yourself and run `rake assets:precompile` directly?

Comment: The process natuarlly take eons upon  yarn install v1.22.17
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.  Compiling... ` but then actually completes.

Answer (score 1):

If asset precompilation is working on the remote server directly then it’s time to look at what conditions SSHKit sets up when capistrano connects to the server:

- Is there a timeout on the ssh connection?
- What environment variables are set when you SSH directly vs in the SSHKit session?

There is a Capistrano `—-trace` option that can help you reveal more info.